# MIPS R4000 Latency and Initiation Intervals

Tags: cpu-architecture

Why MIPS R4000 has latency of 112 cycles and initiation interval of 111 cycles for square root functional unit  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MIPS R4000 Microprocessor User’s Manual](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/cag/raw/documents/R4400_Uman_book_Ed2.pdf) provides a somewhat detailed description of the R4000 floating point pipeline (see section 6.7). For floating point operations, the R4000 FPU provides eight operation stages (mantissa add, divide pipeline, exception test, first multiplier, second multiplier, rounding, operand shift, unpack FP numbers). Double precision square root uses the unpack FP numbers for the first cycle, the exception test for the second, both mantissa add and rounding for the next 108 cycles, mantissa add for the next cycle, and rounding for the last cycle.

Since the unpack FP numbers and exception test (the first two cycles) are not used in later cycles, a following square root operation can start two cycles earlier than if square root was completely unpipelined. This can be diagrammed as follows:

```
         1    2    3   4  ... 110  111  112  114  115
SQRT.D   U    E   A+R A+R     A+R   A    R
SQRT.D        110 stall cycles for second SQRT.D
                                    U    E   A+R  A+R
```

(You can see that the initiation interval counts the cycle when the first SQRT.D is issued, i.e., an initiation interval of zero would mean parallel issue and an initiation interval of one would support back-to-back issue.)